# Have a file from windows to be uploaded to a space and using MacOS download this file having "garbled file name"

Tags: macos

This is maybe as similar to the urldecode. I guess the file name is from a **Simplified Windows System** to be uploaded to a file space.

> "×ÔÓÃ²Î¿¼_config_Ó³Éä¼ü_¿ì½Ý¼ü"

Then, I download this file via MacOS(English Interface). The file name is garbled.

I tried some urldecoder. It is not workable.

I make a question in here. Thanks.

Comment: What is the Windows file name and what is a file space?

Comment: @Mark I forget the real name.

Comment: Do you mean Simplified ***Chinese*** Windows?

Comment: Just guessing here but the encoding used on the original filename is nonsense when copied to an English OS. If you can find the original file name run it through Google Translate, otherwise you are likely out of luck.

Comment: You can figure out the file type via the Unix file command.  Goto terminal. type file  then a space then drag the file to the terminal press return.  example: mac $ file bashrc
bashrc: ASCII English text
mac $

Answer (score 1):

I find out a way to resolve it after your kind comments so that I have a clue to find about "Windows ASCII"...bla...bla.

I get a post real similar to mine. I follow its answer to get the useful hints via google to get a online tool.

What I refer this article to get the hints. 
[How to encode and decode Broken Chinese/Unicode characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967786/how-to-encode-and-decode-broken-chinese-unicode-characters)

The useful tool to converter online to make the garbled word to be readable.
[Online Character Set Fixer](http://www.iosart.com/tools/charset-fixer/)

This article mentions the uploaded file while I download it which is converted to UTF-8. Originally, it is "Windows-1252 encoded". So, I find a useful tool to make it.

The answer is here.

> "×ÔÓÃ²Î¿¼_config_Ó³Éä¼ü_¿ì½Ý¼ü" => "自用参考_config_映射键_快捷键"

Thanks all of you.

Best regards,